# Dependency excluding only one class from maven surefire plugin

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

My question is really simple, thought I haven't found anything online related to it.

Is the maven-surefire-plugin able to have a dependency excluded but at class level and not at group-id:artifact-id level?

My problem:

I have a web project, related to a plain java project A. This A project contains hundred of classes that do a variety of things (connects to the database, sends web services, calculates stuff, manages the logs, context, sessions, etc...) and the dependency is quite strong. Since all unit testing on the web project will be hard to do without this A project I need to have it as a dependency even for the testing. But of course I cannot use some of the classes in there (mainly the DB connection and the session stuff). So I thought that instead of mocking them (because there are like a few dozens of them and I want to do different things with the functions (like writing to a file that it tried to connect or read the "session" from an xml file)) I can create a A-test project and include the classes I want from this new project and exclude the classes I don't need from the A project.

I know I can copy/paste all the project and then replace the classes I want, but if something changes in project A, I then have to maintain it in A-test (and I am very lazy and don't like to work twice). I thought that maybe I could have some kind of plugin in maven that will copy all the other classes (the one I am not... let say 'overriding'), every time. But it seems a waste of time if I just can tell the plugin which classes to use during the test step.

Thanks for your help!